# Is there a quick method to restore the PATH environment var settings for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, path, environment-variables

I seem to have wiped out my path environment variable a while back. I've been slowly restoring things. I have both MATLAB and the MATLAB compiler installed. DLL's I've created from the MATLAB compiler won't run because they can't find the MATLAB compiler runtime dlls. While I did find the particular files that are my immediate problem. I'm wondering if there is a MATLAB *.bat file or command I can type that will restore my path variable to what it was after MATLAB and the Compiler were installed. I'm hoping to forestall future problems.

In case it's version specific I'm running MATLAB R2010b, I'm running a 32 bit version on a 64 bit machine.

[Edit]

I thought I would add that the path I need for running the compiled version was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v714\runtime\win32
```

With luck, that one along with the two suggested in the answer will get me back to the original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have these two directories on the `PATH` (I think the order is important):

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\runtime\win32
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin
```

Obviously you need to adjust the path to match your setup and architecture (those are on a WinXP 32-bit)

Comment: I was hoping for something foolproof like a SetMatLabPaths.bat but I should be able to type all three (these 2 plus the MCR path) without typos. Thanks.

Comment: you might be interested in reading this page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f12-999353.html#br2jauc-33

Comment: Thanks - dumb luck I had them in the proper order.

Answer (score 2):

[restoredefaultpath](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/restoredefaultpath.html) might recover your MATLAB installation. Consider the use of [startup.m](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html), in order to easily undo changes to your environment.

Comment: -1 as I understood the question, the OP wants to restore the **OS PATH** environment variable, not the **MATLAB search path**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a current software maintenance contract for your MATLAB, it may well be that the easy thing to do is just upgrade to the next version of MATLAB since R2011a is out now (unless there is some compelling reason why you **must** develop on R2010b.  Running the software installer should recreate the default environment for MATLAB.  I am, of course, assuming that you have Administrator access on your PC and have permission to install software.